# The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object test.13.csv

Tags: asp-classic

I am working classic ASP project. In this project there is option for users to upload CSV.

Now what is happening is, if I upload CSV file with more than one dot, for example *test.13.csv* then I get:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'test.13.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly

But if I save the same file as *test.csv*, then it takes file properly.

So can anyone tell me how can I allow my code to accept more than one dot in csv file?

I am using following provider :

```
sFileDSN = "Provider=" & msdbProviderString() & ";Data Source=" & objFile.Folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;"""
```

Comment: Did you already try `test_13.csv` to further narrow the problem down on the dot? Also did you check if the file isn't renamed when uploaded?

Comment: @Filburt Hi I tried test_13.csv and it works fine but i need to save as test.13.csv. And also file is not renamed when i uplaod. Is there any solution for this??

Comment: What is the value for `msdbProviderString()`?

Comment: @Filburt msdbProviderString = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

Comment: It seems like there is some logic into the file name which could conflict with your naming requirements - see [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 CSV ConnectionString](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5182767/205233) for details. Maybe you should consider to switch to using an underscore instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose your filename in single quotes like this:

```
sFileDSN = "Provider='" & msdbProviderString() & "';Data Source=" & objFile.Folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;"""
```

Here is a reference, it doesn't specifically mention periods but does address other special characters:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)